# Laravel : JWT refresh token to get user data on same function

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-5.5

I am using `Tymon\JWTAuth` in my app.What I want that when I am going refresh expired token it is return a new generated token but i want to get same user data in same function.

My refresh function :

```
public function refresh()
{
    $token      =  Auth::guard()->refresh();
    $user       = Auth::user(); // Return Null
    return response()->json([
        'status_code'       => 200,
        'token'             => $token,
        'user'              => $user
    ]);
}
```

Response :

```
{
"status_code": 200,
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTkyLjE2OC41LjE1ODo4MDAwL2FwaS9hdXRoL3JlZnJlc2giLCJpYXQiOjE1MzM3OTUyOTUsImV4cCI6MTUzMzc5ODkwMSwibmJmIjoxNTMzNzk1MzAxLCJqdGkiJlMWxiamQ4c1F3UVM0TzhEIiwic3ViIjoxMiwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.vB9unghn2CCJSrzVP9V_Cna-x0Ez--0aF--D7yGfw",
"user": null 
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$user = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->toUser();`
where $token is the refreshed token